# How can I pass JSON to node in a shell script with no libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, bash, shell

If I send JSON through to a node script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

config=`cat some.json`
node script.js $config
```

Then within the node script I am receiving the JSON file as a broken set of args on each new line:

```
[
  '{',
  '"fileTypes":[',
  '"tsx",',
  '"ts",',
  '"js"',
  '],',
  ...
]
```

How can I parse the JSON and send it through as a parameter to Node.

**Note: I don't want to use any libraries such as jq.**

Comment: `node script.js "$(< some.json)"`

Comment: You should [almost always put double-quotes around variable references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-should-i-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (and command substitutions too). [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Comment: Cool good shout, thanks for suggestion works well